# Sorting and filtering by coordinates and letters tuples in Python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, filtering, coordinates

I have a problem with sorting and filtering a list of coordinates and letters. I tried using lambda, but didn't get far as I haven't got much experience with it.

I have a list of coordinate tuples and a letter that goes with that tuple, for example:

```
[((392, 100), 'e'), ((326, 100), 'u'), ((326, 101), 'a'), ((312, 101), 'i')]
```

I want to sort the coordinates so that I can get them in order of rows in a descending manner, so by **descending y first** and **then descending x**. In other words, I need them in the same order as you would read a text: starting up and leftmost coordinate to down and right. The result should be:

```
[((326, 100), 'u'), ((392, 100), 'e'), ((313, 101), 'i'), ((326, 101), 'a')]
```

And then filter out the letters in the order I got, so the final result would be

```
'ueia'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [((392, 100), 'e'), ((326, 100), 'u'), ((326, 101), 'a'), ((312, 101), 'i')]

print( sorted(data, key=lambda k: k[0][::-1] ) )
```

Prints:

```
[((326, 100), 'u'), ((392, 100), 'e'), ((312, 101), 'i'), ((326, 101), 'a')]
```

For letters:

```
print( ''.join(ch for _, ch in sorted(data, key=lambda k: k[0][::-1] ) ) )
```

Prints:

```
ueia
```